# vagrant не открывает нужный сайт

Tags: php, linux, virtualbox, vagrant

Установил, выполнил команду в консоле `vagrant global-status` пишет, что запущен, но как узнать на каком IP и порте запущен этот веб сервер?

в хостсе прописал

```
192.168.56.101 project.local
192.168.100.1 project.local
http://project/
http://m2/
```

заходит только на 192.168.56.101

Answer (score 1):

А какие у вас параметры в файлах VagrantFile (в папке проекта например)? Там могут быть параметры
`config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.56.101"`
Если сервер доступен у вас по 192.168.56.101 значит с этим IP он и поднялся. Если нужен веб-сервер на виртуальной машине, то скорее всего он будет на 80 порте. И зачем у вас в hosts два IP-адреса привязаны к одному имени project.local?

Comment: такой строчки у меня нету config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.56.101"